# backup remote database locally

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have MSsql database on the remote server 
how can I store the backup of this database (locally) on my disk

Answer (score 0):

Map a network drive from your PC to the server, then copy the file to your PC.

\\SERVERNAME\DRIVEWHEREBACKUPFILEIS

Comment: it online server and cant map drive from it

Comment: Does your provider give you a method to move files onto the server?